# Ancient statues actually slow-moving creatures, classroom short story from <= 1980

Tags: story-identification

There's been a couple of questions lately about different creatures/rocks/trees that are living at a different time-rate than humans, and it got me thinking about a story that I'd read when I was in 6th grade and hoping to find again.

I read the story in English, in the US, in 1980. Here's where it gets tricky... the story was actually on a card, maybe 6" x 8", with a small illustration on each side. It was in a teacher's box with many other cards (different stories) in a classroom. We were assigned to read a story/card once a week or so and there might have been questions about the story on the card itself, or we might have just had to note that we read it. I don't think that all the rest of the stories were necessarily Sci-Fi, just short stories to get the attention of a 6th grader. I do not remember any of the other stories.

The story itself was short, as I said, maybe 2 pages (card sides) long, and illustrated with 1 or 2 drawings of 2 large (maybe 30-50') statues that vaguely resembled Easter Island statues but had arms and legs. One statue was sitting/laying on the ground, and the other was standing nearby. There had been pictures of the statues taken quite a few years previously, and a person was in a small plane taking more pictures now. Comparing the pictures it was noticed that the statues were slightly moved (the standing one's hand had moved closer to what appeared to be a gun on it's hip), and it was determined that they weren't statues but rather creatures who lived at a much slower time rate than humans, and that the standing one was coming to the defense of the fallen one.

Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: I am searching the web for exactly the same story. I'm 47 and I remember reading that story when I was in elementary school (so approximately 1980 or maybe slightly earlier), SF Bay Area. Did you locate that story by chance?

Comment: This reminds me of a story in the collection ['It Came From Schenectady' by Barry Longyear](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2221281.It_Came_from_Schenectady) (sorry, I don't recall the story title).

Comment: For some reason this question keeps attracting weird low-value answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is **["Desert Encounter"](https://fantlab-ru.translate.goog/work30828?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp)** by [**I. Rosokhvatsky**](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?19884),
[isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?958073)

Other names: "Aliens from another time", "Newcomers from the next hour", "Meeting in time", "Meeting in the desert".

First published in 1961 (ukrainian version).

[image]

**Plot**

> In the middle of the Asian desert, not far from the remains of an
> ancient city, archaeologists have discovered two strange statues of a
> man and a woman. The mystery of the statues haunts researchers.
> According to one of the hypotheses, a spaceship once landed in the
> desert, and intelligent beings left these statues as a sign of their
> stay on Earth. The truth is somewhat different...

**"Movement" part:**

> On a photo, the female statue is standing straight with her
> hands down, and now she changed position: legs slightly bent at the
> knees, hand extended to the leg where it was sampled.
> And man is standing half-turned to her, took a step
> forward, as if protecting the woman. Right hand is extended and
> clasps some subject.

[Full story (russian)](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/add-on/xussr_mr/rosoh031.htm?1)

[Full story at archive.org, english version](https://archive.org/details/russiansciencefi0000magi_k3n2/page/n8/mode/1up?view=theater)

Comment: This sounds very close to the story described in the question -- did it appear on reading cards also?

Comment: @Basya how can one check them?

Comment: Holy crap, I think you found it! That picture looks very close to what my 45+ year memory is producing. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome=)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - no idea; you knew the story; I hope you might have some information about that which we could edit into the question.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know the particular story or author, but I can identify the story-cards-in-a-box for you: they were probably from an [SRA Reading Laboratory Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Research_Associates), which have been around since 1957. I used to *adore* SRA cards & stories. :) I found a [link where you can preview](http://www.srareadinglabs.com/print/pages/reading_labs/vocab.php) some of the cards on PDFs, so you can see if those are the correct format for the cards you are remembering. I'm not sure how you would then search for a certain story/author. Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Wow, that is almost certainly the series. Great find, thank you! I'll use this info as a new research vector and if I find the story I'll come back and mark this answer accepted.

Comment: I've tried using sitecomber to locate any stories on their site about statue/s and Easter Island with no success

Comment: Thanks again, FSC - I marked this answer as acceptable since it was the most helpful. I'd forgotten about that technicality - glad it existed!

 
(Somebody had posted an answer that some admin deleted because (I'm assuming) it was supposed to be a comment; that answer also had some useful information, but I'd closed a tab intending to read it later and then it was deleted. Hopefully I'll see it again.)

Comment: YAY! \o/ ...2nd answer was me too. Info: try a library for a physical copy - find via OCLC WorldCat. [My search = ~50 kits](http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=kw%3Areading+au%3AScience+Research+Associates.&fq=yr%3A1957..1980+%3E+%3E+ln%3Aeng+%3E+mt%3Ajuv&qt=advanced&dblist=638#x0%253Akit-format). Adv. Search params: Keyword: reading; Auth: Science Research Associates; Yr: 1957-1980; Audience: Juv.; Lang.: Eng; then filter Format=Kit. Beware name diffs! [Here's a good one](http://www.worldcat.org/title/sra-reading-laboratory-iiia/oclc/4316621), in 25 libraries. Happy hunting! Thrilled to help. :)

Comment: Did the actual specific story ever get identified? The accepted answer seems to be "somewhere in this long long list is probably the story"

Answer (score 4):

Per PMar's partial answer (and an earlier, now deleted, answer by user67049 turned into a comment), this could be "[Adagio](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?275761)" by Barry M. Longyear as collected in [*It Came from Schenectady*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2221281.It_Came_from_Schenectady):

> "Adagio" feels like a Twilight Zone story written by George R.R. Martin. (Why, yes, I am thinking of Sandkings, though there are a number of classic TZ eps that fit the mould as well.) A ship crashes on an alien world, and the survivors are bored stiff waiting for rescue. One crewman discovers that certain rocks in the area are in fact slow moving creatures. The man uses his speed to convince the creatures that he's a supernatural creature and orders them to engage in bloody wars against each other.

Its *Omni* publication can be found online [here](http://www.williamflew.com/omni72a.html). There is an illustration with Easter Island heads, but it's a joke cartoon and no arms or legs:
[image: Easter Island comedian]

I don't think this is a match, actually, as it's longer (5-6 pages), the aliens look like rocks, not statues, and it's primarily about a holy war. The only statues that appear are at the very end, and they're static ones of the explorers built by the aliens.

Comment: I just read "Adagio" days ago in an attempt to find the SRA story. I found it to be a depressing story fit for adults, of a crashed ship, people dying, and the last three of them (before one another) communicating with the alien rocks, and the last two of them determined to kill each other. They survived the alien atmosphere and lack of food by somehow changing to be more rocklike themselves. Then they *still* tried to kill each other. A ship to the site a few hundred years later saw them as only a wrecked ship surrounding two statues "in mortal combat". I STILL want to find the SRA story.