# Sci-fi book where a guy turns to rock

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book 30 plus years ago... I remember the man, it seems, is on another planet and is trying to climb this mountain which he's having trouble doing.  All the while turning into the rock. He reaches the top and falls down the other side but gets stuck because he's now the rock too. Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Was the character named Benjamin Grimm?

Comment: I don't remember. But I remember he got stuck on the other side of the mountain...so I thought that's what the title was. Can't find it though

Comment: My Side of the Mountain and On the Far Side of the Mountain - but they don't match your story details.

Comment: If I remember correctly he climbed the rock for most of the book...I'm not sure but I think a whole book.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [The Crystal World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/70255.The_Crystal_World) by J.G. Ballard?

In the synopsis it has a lot of elements of the same nature; only it's a forest; not a mountain; also the publish date of 1988 would put it roughly 30 ish years ago

> J. G. Ballard's fourth novel, which established his reputation as a writer of extraordinary talent and imaginative powers, tells the story of a physician specializing in the treatment of leprosy who is invited to a small outpost in the interior of Africa. Finding the roadways blocked, he takes to the river, and embarks on a frightening journey through a strange petrified forest whose area expands daily, affecting not only the physical environment but also its inhabitants.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a story by Barry Longyear called ["Adagio"](http://www.williamflew.com/omni72a.html).

From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/152355/23243):

> "Adagio" feels like a Twilight Zone story written by George R.R. Martin. (Why, yes, I am thinking of Sandkings, though there are a number of classic TZ eps that fit the mould as well.) A ship crashes on an alien world, and the survivors are bored stiff waiting for rescue. One crewman discovers that certain rocks in the area are in fact slow moving creatures. The man uses his speed to convince the creatures that he's a supernatural creature and orders them to engage in bloody wars against each other.

Comment: I added one summary I found. If you have a better one that suggests why this is the correct answer, please add it.

Comment: No That's not it but I liked it!